# non functioning of touch pad & mouse

Tags: touchpad

Very often I find that the cursor is not moving and the touch pad is also not working while working with ubuntu 11.10. I then have to do the task by attaching external mouse. Please help.

Comment: Is it that the touchpad is disabled while typing, or is it just not working at all ? What touchpad do you have ?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information?

Comment: @JorgeCastro now can we rectify the touch pad of laptop.

Answer (score 2):

I've very similar problem with touch-pad (I haven't mouse). I tried this solution:

1. Run "Mouse and Touch Pad".
2. Open "Touch Pad" tab.
3. Untick checkbox "Disable touchpad while typing".

I'm not sure about the solution. But maybe it can help you.